TypeError: function missing 1 required positional arguments
I keep on getting an error about missing required arguments for line 12 (oled =...)in my code for a Raspberry Pi Pico H running Micropython
from machine import Pin, UART, I2C
import utime, time

#\___\_
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C
#\___\_
from micropyGPS import MicropyGPS
#\_______________________________________________________\_

#Oled I2C connection
i2c = I2C(0, sda=Pin(8), scl=Pin(9), freq=200000)
oled = SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c)
i2c_2 = I2C(1, sda=Pin(14), scl=Pin(15), freq=200000)
oled_2 = SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c_2)

#GPS Module UART Connection
gps_module = UART(1, baudrate=9600, tx=Pin(5), rx=Pin(6))
print(gps_module)

TIMEZONE = -5
my_gps = MicropyGPS(TIMEZONE)

# 

MPY: soft reboot
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
TypeError: function missing 1 required positional arguments
I tried moving all of the pins to different outputs, defining the I2C function with 4 arguments instead of 3, and the code is not happy either way.

Syntax looks OK according to here. Did you have to install the ssd1306 library and if so where did you get it from? Can you have a look at its source code to see what parameters its __init__ method is expecting?
